# How to reshape a data frame to create binary combinations using another column in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, group-by, reshape

I have a dataset that includes **names** and the **companies** they have ever worked in.

```
name     company
 A        Mazda
 B        Benz
 C        Mazda
 D        Toyota
 E        Benz
 F        Mazda
 E        BMW
 G        Benz
 A        Toyota
 C        Toyota
 B        BMW
```

I would like to use **dplyr** and  sort data by showing any combination of two names who ever worked in the same company. The order of names don't matter, for example, A and C combination has no difference with C and A combination. So the favourable outcome would be

```
name 1     name 2     company
 A            C         Mazda
 A            C         Toyota
 A            F         Mazda
 B            E         Benz
 B            E         BMW
 C            F         Mazda
 B            G         Benz
 E            G         Benz
 D            C         Toyota 
 A            C         Toyota
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Function that take in a df that only contains one company names
company_combination <- function(data) {
  stopifnot(length(unique(data$company)) == 1)
  # generate a empty tibble if there only one record for the company
  if (nrow(data) == 1) { 
    names_comb <- tibble()
  } else {
    # get the company name
    company <- first(data[["company"]])
    # generate name combination from the name list and put it into tibble of two columns
    names_comb <- as_tibble(t(combn(x = unique(data[["name"]]), m = 2)))
    # change column names to name_1 & name_2
    names(names_comb) <- c("name_1", "name_2")
    # Add the company name into the new name combination df and return the result
    names_comb %<>% mutate(company = company)
  }
  names_comb
}

# Here there are three steps
df %>%
  # 1st split original data into list of dataframe group by company
  split(.$company) %>%
  # Then apply the company_combination function for each company df
  # Result of this command is a new list of dataframe as result of the function
  map(., company_combination) %>%
  # Then bind them all together back to one dataframe.
  bind_rows()
```

Here is the result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   name_1 name_2 company
   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
 1 B      E      Benz   
 2 B      G      Benz   
 3 E      G      Benz   
 4 B      E      BMW    
 5 A      C      Mazda  
 6 A      F      Mazda  
 7 C      F      Mazda  
 8 A      C      Toyota 
 9 A      D      Toyota 
10 C      D      Toyota
```

Comment: your output is different from mine, did you create a different df?

Comment: I use the same data you provided. The output is different but I think mine is more complete - If you have three people at a company you should have 3 combination of 2. While you sample output is only 2 combination.

Comment: thnaks you are right, I am going to run your code and will keep you posted.

Comment: I get this error ` Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : length(unique(data$company)) == 1 is not TRUE` . I see you mentioned the same error, but obviously I have more than 1 in some companies or lets say I have duplicates in companies

Comment: Can you share what code lead to that? Do you have the line `split`? And make sure that you adjust the function to match with the column name in your data as well.

Comment: I get error at this line :  `map(., company_combination)`. And this is the error : `  Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(x = data[["name"]], m = 2) ` .

Comment: I added unique command to ensure no duplicated combination generated - Also how many records are there in your data?

Comment: thanks, well the data set has around 40k rows. I created another data set with 20 rows and got this error :  `Error in combn(x = data[["name"]], m = 2) : n < m`.

Comment: I think I coded it in a different way: `df  %>% select(company,name) %>% mutate(name_dup=name) %>%  group_by(company)  %>%
expand(name_1=name,name_2=name_dup) %>% filter(name_1 !=name_2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228554/discussion-between-sinh-nguyen-and-alex).